# Is it possible to use scanf() to split string with space when the separator includes a space?

Tags: c

Input string is `"attach -P123"`. Before I used `scanf("%500s -P%d",command,&number)` to get command and number, and as result the command is `"attach"` and the number is `123`. Now I need to input `"get item -P123"` and want the command as `"get item"`, and I stucked and came here.

The `scanf("%500[0-9a-zA-Z ] -P%d",command,&number)` is the nearest answer I found. But there is a space at the end of the command: `"get item "` or `"attach "`. Is it possible to remove it with some other format string?

Unfortunately, I find that the input can be something like this: `"HQ-24@11SCEV:你好 something.exe -P123"`, and I need `command` as `"HQ-24@11SCEV:你好 something.exe"`, so things may have gone too far. This was part of my reverse engineering efforts, but it looks like I should find other methods.

Comment: scanf is the worst choice for similar tasks. Write parsing function yourself. It will take much shorter time than the time you spend trying to figure out why it is not possible with scanf

Comment: @fiov This %500\[0-9a-zA-Z ] is not a C standard format string. Do not use it.

Comment: In general it is better to read the whole thing with `fgets` then parse afterwards, using `strtol`, `strtok` or whatever other functions that may be handy for your format.

Comment: You can read the entire line from the file with [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets), then [remove the newline character](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2693776/12149471), and then use [`strrchr`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strrchr) to find the position of the last space character on the line.

Comment: @VladfromMoscow: actually `%500[0-9a-zA-Z ]` is a correct `scanf` directive: it will accept up to 500 characters in the set of US letters and digits and the space character.  The use of `-` for a range of letters such as `a-z` is implementation defined and the characters in this range typically depend on the execution character set. In ASCII you get exactly the 26 lowercase letters, whereas in EBCDIC the set might also include some other characters such as `~`.  Assuming ASCII is usually not a problem and assuming a non perverse `scanf` implementation makes sense too.

Comment: @chqrlie I did not say that the format is invalid. I said that such a specification is not standard and should not be used.

Comment: You could always read the entire line and then loop `strchr (str, '-')` and check if the next char is `'P'` to identify your option location. or use `strcspn()`/`strspn()` in combination, or `strtok()` with the delim as `"-"` to accomplish the same thing (you would still need to check the next (first) char of the token for `'P'`)

Comment: @fiov Could the command contain a `'-'`?

Comment: @VladfromMoscow – If you said "_If a `-` character is in the scanlist and is not the first, nor the second where the first character is a `^`, nor the last character, the behavior is implementation-defined_", then you'd be quoting the standard and clarifying what you meant.  Or you could say that scanlists using a dash to specify character ranges are implementation-defined; or something similar.

Answer (score 1):

Applied to `"get item -P123"`, the `scanf` conversion format `"%500[0-9a-zA-Z ] -P%d"` will parse multiple words separated by spaces (`get item` ) and stop on the `-` or any other character which is not part of the set.  The space before `-P` would skip other whitespace such as TABs, but if none are present, it is not a match failure, then `-P` matches the `-P` in the string and `%d` matches and converts `123`.

This format will almost achieve your purpose but the trailing space will be stored at the end of `command`, so you might want to trimm that off before comparing with command strings.

Here is a sample program:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    char line[800];
    char command[501];
    int port;

    while (fgets(line, sizeof line, stdin)) {
        switch (sscanf(line, "%500[0-9a-zA-Z ] -P%d", command, &number)) {
          case 2:
            printf("command: '%s', port %d\n", command, port);
            break;
          case 1:
            printf("command: '%s', no port\n", command);
            break;
          default:
            printf("no command. line: %s\n", line);
            break;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hmm, `command` will be "get item " and not the desired "get item" -- Oh, I expected code to achieve OP's goal.  Now I see the "but the trailing space will be stored" is the answer's text.  IMO, that caveat deserves to be a code comment.

Comment: As it stands, leading blanks will also be accepted and stored — and those would have to be trimmed.  Putting a space before the `%500[…]` part would eliminate the leading space, of course.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `scanf()`, then the best you can probably do is use it to identify the location of the `-P` so that you can efficiently remove the trailing white space.

To get the location, you can use the `%n` option.

Instead of using, `%500[0-9a-zA-Z ]` you can choose to use the shorter `%500[^-]` instead, if it matches your intention.

For example:

```
char command[501];
int number;
int len;
int r;
r = scanf("%500[^-]%n-P%d", command, &len, &number);
assert(r == 2); /* %n doesn't add to parse count */
assert(len <= 500);
assert(command[len] == '\0');
while ((len > 0) && (command[len-1] == ' ') --len;
command[len] = '\0';
```